# About Getzler's rescaling operator

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mathematical-physics

I am trying to read the heat kernel proof of the Atiyah-Singer index theorem by the method of Getzler's rescaling method. Here, we define an operator $$(\delta_{\lambda}\phi)(t,x)=\sum_{j=0}^n \lambda^{-j}\phi(\lambda^2t,\lambda x)$$
$\phi$ is defined on $\mathbb R^{+}\times U$ with values in $Cl(T_qM)\otimes End(W)$ where $W$ is the twisted bundle for Clifford module bundle $E=S\otimes W$. We can imagine $\phi(t,x)$ as terms like asymptotic expansion of heat kernels $k(t,x)$ and identify it with CLifford algebra basis.

And we define the Getzler's operator as $\delta_{\lambda} A \delta_{\lambda}^{-1}$ for some operators (For the square of the Dirac operator $D^2$, this is actually the rescaled Dirac laplacian $D_{\lambda}^2$, which has the rescaled heat kernel, this transforms the asymptotic expansion with $t\to0^{+}$ to rescaled $\lambda\to 0^{+}$)

My question is how does the inverse $\delta_{\lambda}^{-1} $ work ? How to calculate it on operators like $A=\partial_t$, the example shows that this is equal to $\delta_{\lambda} \partial_{t} \delta_{\lambda}^{-1}=\lambda^{-2}\partial_{t}$

Comment: @Jean Marie I've tried to add some backgroud., hope this does not affect the reading...

Answer (score 1):

I would just go about calculating it in the following way:

1. Calculate $\delta_{\lambda} A$ and $A \delta_{\lambda}$ by letting it act on arbitrary $\phi$ as defined above.
2. Compare both expressions and "compose them" with  the inverse of $\delta_{\lambda}$ on the right.

For example, for $A=\partial_t$:

(1.1) $(\delta_{\lambda} \partial_t) (\phi(t,x))=(\delta_{\lambda}) (\partial_t\phi(t,x))=\sum_{j=0}^n \lambda^{-j}(\partial_t\phi)(\lambda^2t,\lambda x)$

(1.2) Using the chain rule:$(\partial_t \delta_{\lambda} ) (\phi(t,x))=\partial_t(\delta_{\lambda}\phi)(t,x)=\partial_t\sum_{j=0}^n \lambda^{-j}\phi(\lambda^2t,\lambda x)=\sum_{j=0}^n \lambda^{-j}\partial_t(\phi(\lambda^2t,\lambda x))=\sum_{j=0}^n \lambda^{-j}(\partial_t\phi)(\lambda^2t,\lambda x)\lambda^2=\lambda^2(\delta_{\lambda} \partial_t) (\phi(t,x))$

(2) From these calculations, $\delta_{\lambda} \partial_t=\lambda^{-2}\partial_t \delta_{\lambda}$ which you can write as $\delta_{\lambda} \partial_t \delta_{\lambda}^{-1}=\lambda^{-2}\partial_t$

**Edit**

If you look at Berline-Getzler-Vergne´s book, Getzler´s rescaling is introduced in page 140 in a slightly different manner as your case: for such a $\phi$, we have a decomposition in $\phi_{[i]}\in Cl_i(T_qM)$ so that $\phi=\sum_i \phi_{[i]}$. This decomposition comes from the grading of the space of differential forms $\Lambda T_qM$ (by considering $\Lambda^i T_qM$, the forms of degree $i$), which is transferred to the Clifford algebra via the isomorphism of graded modules between both of them (the quantization map or its inverse, the symbol map).

Now the (Getzler´s) rescaling is defined as:

$$(\delta_u \phi)(t,x)=\sum_{i=0}^n u^{-i/2}\phi(ut,u^{1/2}x)_{[i]}$$

This rescaling behaves well with respect to the grading: we can first decompose our $\phi$ in a sum of $\phi_{[i]}$'s and then apply the rescaling and obtain the same result as just applying directly the rescaling, since $$(\phi_{[i]})_{[j]}=\begin{cases} \phi_{[i]} & i=j \\ 0 & i\neq j \end{cases}$$

This means it is enough to know how the inverse acts on each $\phi_{[i]}$ and one can check this has to be the natural one:

$$(\delta_u^{-1} \phi_{[i]})(t,x)= u^{i/2}\phi(u^{-1}t,u^{-1/2}x)_{[i]}$$

giving

$$(\delta_u^{-1} \phi)(t,x)=\sum_{i=0}^n u^{i/2}\phi(u^{-1}t,u^{-1/2}x)_{[i]}$$

For your example, derivating with respect to the $t$ variable using the chain rule gives us a $u^{-1}$ and note that the parameter $u$ in Getzler´s expression acts as your $\lambda^2$, as desired.